# play mp3 with monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer

I'm building an application using monotouch. Basically I need to play a mp3 as soon as the application loads.
On the main.cs I added this snippet before pushing the main controller:

```
AVAudioPlayer player = new AVAudioPlayer();
NSUrl mediaFile = NSUrl.FromFilename("Content/Audio/music1.mp3");

player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(mediaFile);
player.Delegate = new PlayerDelegate();

if(player.PrepareToPlay()){
  player.Play();
}
```

But when I start the application I can hear the sound for about half second and then nothing.
Is this code correct or there is something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to provide an answer without more context, like more code :-)

I suspect your `AVAudioPlayer`, if used as a local variable, could be collected by the garbage collector (GC) when the method (is it `FinishedLaunching` ?) returns.

If this is the case then *promoting* your local `player` variable into a field would ensure a reference is kept to the `AVAudioPlayer` instance and should allow it to play without being interrupted (or crashing).

If I'm wrong then please **edit** your question and provide us with more context and we should be able to help you further.

Comment: I just call a function to play the audio from inside

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        PlayAudio();
    }

and the PlayAudio function contains the code on my question

Comment: Sorry, the status is not clear ? does it work (I'll assume so since you accepted the answer) ? The important bit to remember is that the `player` continue to work/play *after* `FinishedLaunching` returns, so the instance of that object still needs to be *alive* (and not collected).

Comment: Yes I promoted the variable into a field and it worked. I presume the problem was related to the action of the GC. Many thanks poupou

Answer (score 0):

Try registering for the AVAudioPlayerDelegate and starting the music back up again in the audioPlayerEndInterruption method.

Comment: Hi Ralfonso, thanks for your reply. I tried something like this:
    `AVAudioPlayer player = new AVAudioPlayer();`
    `NSUrl mediaFile = NSUrl.FromFilename("Content/Audio/music1.mp3");`
    `player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(mediaFile);`
    `player.Delegate = new AVAudioPlayerDelegate();`
   
    `player.EndInterruption += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {`
    `    player.Play();`
    `};`
   
    `if(player.PrepareToPlay()){`
    `    player.Play();`
    `}`

But now it's even worst. The application crashes when it starts playing

Comment: I'm not too familiar with MonoTouch, but I know that when developing in Objective-C, Xcode does a lot of things silently when resources are added to the project.  Make sure there are no possible file format errors (try a .wav), or load the file from the main bundle.  An example is here: [link]http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Playing_Audio_on_an_iPhone_using_AVAudioPlayer_(iOS_4)#Support_Audio_Formats

Answer (score 0):

Now it's really easy:

```
            //enable audio
            AudioSession.Initialize();

            //load the sound
            sound = SystemSound.FromFile("Sounds/rev.wav");
            sound.PlaySystemSound();
```